# Where is Activity History Stored on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, privacy

Under Privacy > Activity History, I have "Store my activity history on this device" checked.

[image]

But I can't find anywhere that says where that data is actually stored.

I'm aware I can go to this URL and view and download the data:
https://account.microsoft.com/privacy

But if the data is already on my device, why do I have to go to a website to get access to it?

If I download the data from that website, it comes as a CSV file (which is good)

But where on my local machine is that data stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I can't find anywhere that says where that data is actually stored.

It's not stored in a single place as there are different kinds of history:

> Windows gathers the following set of information:
>
> - History of Edge browsing

You can see your browsing history by selecting going to Settings and more > History > Manage history

> - Google search history

That's stored at Google unless you configure it not to do so. Stored locally in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default`

> - Location information (if enabled)

Stored in the cloud.

> - Voice commands for Cortana

Stored in the cloud.

> - The Timeline feature in Windows 10 is used.

Stored in the cloud and also in the file `ActivitiesCache.db` with the path `\Users\%profile name%\AppData\Local\ConnectedDevicesPlatform\L.%profile name%\`.

Source: [How To View Activity History On Windows 10 PC](https://wethegeek.com/view-activity-history-on-windows-10/)

See Also: [No Time to Waste | Group-IB Blog](https://www.group-ib.com/blog/windows10-timeline-for-forensics/)

Comment: Great! There's a .db file in the folder you mention that is a Sqlite file.  It opens easily with any app that can view sqlite (I used DataGrip).  I also found this article (PDF) that explains how to parse some of the binary entries in that db: https://kacos2000.github.io/WindowsTimeline/WindowsTimeline.pdf